# plotting histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a histogram in R. My bins are [1, 1.25, 1.33, 1.5, 1.67, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.33, 2.5, 2.67, 2.75, 3]

This is how I tried to do it but I am not getting the right plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=relevance, data = train) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 1.25, 1.33, 1.5, 1.67, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.33, 2.5, 2.67, 2.75, 3)) +
scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram? Histograms typically have even spacing between breaks

Comment: you should include the loading of your package (`ggplot2`) in your code snippet. Also please include data for train so that there's a reproducible example to work with (or choose a builtin dataset). I think you're also missing a closing `)`

Comment: my x is discrete and only takes those values. so I am interested only in those bins.

Comment: If `relevance` is discrete, why are you using `scale_x_**continuous**`?

Comment: I am new to R. What should I use? @Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reproducible example is typically preferred. Also note, you're using `ggplot`

```
# base r
set.seed(12345)
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x, breaks= c(-Inf,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3, Inf), xlim= c(-4,4))

# ggplot2, using discrete data
library(ggplot2)
x3 <- rpois(1000, 5)
x2 <- data.frame(x3)
qplot(data= x2, x=x3, geom= "histogram") + scale_x_discrete(breaks= names(table(x3)))
```

Comment: I have gaps between the columns. Can this be fixed? @Alex

Comment: I gave you two solutions. The base R solution doesn't have gaps. with ggplot, the gaps are an **intentional** design choice to make histograms more readable. If you want ggplot without gaps, you could use a barchart-- `geom_bar`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=relevance),data =train) + 
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x="Relevance score", y="Count")
```